# Safari stacking issue with 3d transformed elements

Tags: css

I've read through numerous similar issues regarding this topic, but haven't been able to solve my problem using any of those advices, so giving it a shot to see what I might be doing wrong / how I can solve this :)

I'm trying to get #item-2 to stack in front of #item-1 . This works fine in Chrome etc..but fails in Safari. Any advice would be greatly appritiated.

I have the following html elements:

```css
 html,
 body {
   min-height: 100%;
   backround: #FFF;
 }
 * {
   -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 #scene-bg,
 #scene {
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
 }
 #grid {
   -webkit-perspective: 865px;
   -moz-perspective: 865px;
   perspective: 865px;
   width: 987px;
   height: 720px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index: 1;
   border: 1px solid;
 }
 .inner {
   width: 100%;
   height: inherit;
   position: relative;
   top: 17px;
   left: 6px;
   border: 1px solid;
   -webkit-transform: rotateX(-0.3302deg) rotateY(20.5164deg) rotateZ(-0.8716deg);
   -moz-transform: rotateX(-0.3302deg) rotateY(20.5164deg) rotateZ(-0.8716deg);
   transform: rotateX(-0.3302deg) rotateY(20.5164deg) rotateZ(-0.8716deg);
 }
 #item-1 {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: inherit;
   -webkit-transition: background .25s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: background .25s ease-out;
   transition: background .25s ease-out;
   background: red;
 }
 #item-2 {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 99999;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   background: blue;
 }
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div class="inner">
    <div id="item-1">
    </div>
    <!-- /#item-1 -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.inner -->
  <div id="item-2">
  </div>
  <!-- /#item-2 -->
</div>
<!--/#grid -->
```

Comment: what are you looking to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to get #item-2 to stack in front of #item-1 . This works fine in Chrome etc..but fails in -webkit- browsers. In -webkit- browsers, #item-1 is rendered infront of #item-2 :(. 

Basically I'm trying to control the stacking order of the items while one of the elements are 3d transformed, and the other is not.

Comment: chrome *is* a webkit browser is it not?

Comment: Sorry..I've edited my post to clarify that the issue, to my knowledge, only occurs in Safari.

Comment: have a look at the resources section [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d)